# ENOENT: no such file or directory: even if the folder exists

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I tried to submit a form through postman, but I keep getting the no such file error, The pdf is not getting saved to the path mentioned in local pc, even though the file exists. Node keeps throwing the error :

> [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory
>
> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'D:\lims\Generate_PDF_for_Forms\ViralFlexSeqSubmissionForm_Dash_7-2-2019_13:37:42.pdf']
>         errno: -4058,
>         code: 'ENOENT',
>         syscall: 'open',
>         path:
>          'D:\lims-customer\Generate_PDF_for_Forms\ViralFlexSeqSubmissionForm_Dash_7-2-2019_13:37:42.pdf' .

**Brief Code :**

```
    const printer = new pdfMakePrinter(fontDescriptor);
    const doc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition);
    // functions getDateAndTime returns date in mm/dd/yyyy format followed by time in HH:MM:SS:Milliseconds
    const dateAndTime = getDateAndTime();
    const pdfName = 'ViralFlexSeqSubmissionForm' + '_' + user.lastName + '_' + dateAndTime + '.pdf';
    console.log("HereYouGo::"+pdfName);
    doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('Generate_PDF_for_Forms/' + pdfName).on('error', (err) => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    );
```

Comment: Where's the code? You just posted a generic error without specifying any details.

Comment: Thank you for replying @devio Added now, the same codebase works in production environment.But when i try to set it up on local, it throws the ENOENT error.

Comment: gave up on windows as it was time consuming to fix the issue and set it up from scratch in Linux environment and now it works all fine.